# Graduation election: interest check

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

Literature Stack Exchange [left beta in December 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/340816). This meant, among other things, that we might have "full-site moderator elections" (or "graduation election") scheduled in 2022 or 2023. We didn't have a graduation election last year (organising elections for 59 sites takes time), so let's see if we can get one this year. Before we do that, it would be good to find out whether there would be sufficient interest, i.e. sufficient nominations, for such an election. That's because full-site moderator elections are a bit different from the pro-tempore elections we have had so far.

- In a **graduation election** there are as many slots as there are moderator positions, i.e. three on small sites such as our own. This means that even moderators who wish to continue moderating would need to nominate themselves and stand for election. *As a rule*, there should be more candidates than available positions.
- In a **pro-tempore moderator election** there are as many slots as there are moderators who are stepping down. Also, on some sites, an interest check for a graduation election didn't get enough potential nominations, so the planned graduation election was basically scrapped and replaced with a pro-tempore election. (For an, see [Moderator election canceled due to insufficient nominees; what happens next?](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/889/11052) on French Language SE.)

The intent of this post is to find out **how many users would be willing to nominate themselves as potential moderators**. So please comment on or respond to this post if you would be interested. Since I'll be handing in my moderator diamond, we'll need to have at least four potential candidates for a graduation election.

Comment: I'm not interested in nominating myself, but am I allowed to nominate @bobble?

Comment: @verbose It is not possible to nominate other people. (I think that only works for sites coming out of private beta.)

Comment: This is perhaps an odd answer but I would consider standing if it was necessary to help the site "graduate".

Comment: I'd run (especially if it's needed to have an election) with the caveat that I'm quite imperfect for the role.